# i want show audio slider to my card when user click on that card it will play song and show the slider to that card only

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

[this is my listtile of songs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QhCC.png)

here is the img which contain card in the card the listtile

help me to show the slider to my this music app such like this

**help me to show such slider to my flutter app**

**here is the img which contain card in the card the listtile **

help me to show the slider to my this music app such like this

[this is how i want to show the slider in my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42McC.jpg)

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:punjabi_collection/services/music_model.dart' as mu;
import '../services/api_manage.dart';

class Musicplaylist extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MusicplaylistState createState() => _MusicplaylistState();
}

class _MusicplaylistState extends State<Musicplaylist> {
  AudioPlayer audioPlayer = new AudioPlayer();
  Duration duration = new Duration();
  Duration position = new Duration();
  bool playing = false;

  mu.Data _data;
  List<mu.Audio> _audio = [];
  bool _loading;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loading = true;
    _getData();
    initPlayer();
  }

  _getData() async {
    _data = await Services.getData();
    _audio = _data.audio;

    setState(() {
      _loading = false;
    });
  }

  void initPlayer() {
    audioPlayer = new AudioPlayer();

    audioPlayer.durationHandler = (d) => setState(() {
          duration = d;
        });

    audioPlayer.positionHandler = (p) => setState(() {
          position = p;
        });
  }

  void seekToSecond(int second) {
    Duration newDuration = Duration(seconds: second);

    audioPlayer.seek(newDuration);
  }

  Widget slider() {
    return Slider.adaptive(
        activeColor: Colors.blue,
        inactiveColor: Colors.orange,
        min: 0.0,
        value: position.inSeconds.toDouble(),
        max: duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
        onChanged: (double value) {
          setState(() {
            seekToSecond(value.toInt());
            value = value;
          });
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        title: Text('Punjabi songs',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20.0)),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search, size: 30.0, color: Colors.black),
              onPressed: null),
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.favorite, size: 30.0, color: Colors.redAccent),
              onPressed: () {})
        ],
      ),
      body: _loading
          ? Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
            ))
          : Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
                // physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: _data.audio.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                
                  mu.Audio audio = _audio[index];
                  return Card(
                    elevation: 0.0,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        ListTile(
                          onTap: () async {
                            audioPlayer.pause();
                            debugPrint('${audio.title}');
                            // await audioPlayer.setUrl(
                            //     
                            //         audio.image);
                          },
                          leading: Image(
                            image: audio.hashCode.hashCode.hashCode.isEven
                                ? AssetImage(
                                    './assets/blue.png',
                                  )
                                : AssetImage('./assets/playb.png'),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                          title: Text(
                            audio.title,
                          ),
                          trailing: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.favorite_border_rounded,
                                size: 30.0,
                                color: Colors.red,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () async {
                                int status = await audioPlayer.play(
                                  
                                      audio.image.replaceAll(" ", "%20"),
                                );
                                if (status == 1) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    playing = true;
                                  });
                                } else {
                                  setState(() {
                                    playing = false;
                                  });
                                }
                              }),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap slider inside [Visibility](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html) and can control its visibility and functionality of slider or playing music using a [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) wrapping your listtile or card widget. Here is sample code for you that shows and hides the slider when you click on the list item:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: 500,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          //   physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: items == null ? 0 : items.length,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),

          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (selected != items[index])
                    selected = items[index];
                  else
                    selected = null;
                });
              },
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      CircleAvatar(
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            items[index][0].toUpperCase(),
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 8,
                      ),
                      Expanded(child: Text(items[index])),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Visibility(
                    visible: selected == items[index],
                    child: slider(),
                  ),
                  Divider(),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: thanks you !! this suggestion. help me to out this error :)